# What SSL certificate do I need?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm developing software which will be deployed using clickonce (on the website foo.com), and which will then connect to my server using WCF with an encrypted transport

So I need an SSL certificate which will :

- Identify my foo.com website has really being my website
- Identify the exe I deploy using clickonce as being genuine
- Identify my application server has really being my application server.

I also want my SSL certificate to be signed by an authority known to the public (ie, firefox or windows won't ask the user to install the authority's certificate first !)

What SSL certificate would you buy?

I've browsed the Verisign website, the "Secure Site EV" certificate costs 1150€ a year (the "Pro" version seems useful only for compatibility with older browsers)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for two different types of certificates:

1 - SSL Certificate - for authentication of your website/application server.

2 - Code Signing Certificate - for integrity/authentication of the exe you deliver.

Typically those are two different certificates, with two different certificate profiles.  At the very least, you need one certificate with two different key usages or extended key usages.

A few thoughts in no specific order:

- Check your targeted browsers, they should each have a set of preconfigured root certificates - those are the most widely recognized public certificate sources.  I'd probably check both Firefox and IE. Certificate vendors known to me as big names are - Versign, GeoTrust, RSA, Thawte, Entrust.  But there's also GoDaddy and many others.  Anything that comes in the delivered browser as a Trusted Root Certificate, will allow you to connect to your users without additional greif.
- I suggest Googling for both "code signing certificate" and "SSL certificate".
- How you configure your site will determine whether or not your website is validated or your authentication server is validated.  If the certificate is stored on the apps server, then your user is getting SSL encryption all the way to the server.  But many sites put the SSL certificate a little farther forward - like on a firewall, and then stage a collection of apps servers behind it.  I don't see a security flaw in that, so long as the networking is carefully configured.  To the outside users, both configurations will look the same - they'll get the lock on their browsers and a certificate that tells them that www.foo.com is offering it's credentials.

I'm seeing pretty great deals for SSL Certificates:
 - GoDaddy - $12.99
 - Register.com - $14.99

But they aren't necessarily *code signing certifiates*. For example, while GoDaddy's SSL Cert is $12.99, their [code signing certs](http://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/ssl/signing.asp?isc=sslqgo003a&ci=13314) are $199.99!  That's part of many certificate vendors business models - lure you in with cheap SSL Certs, and make you pay for code signing.  A case could be made that code signing certificates are relatively higher liability.  But also... they have to subsidize the cheap SSL certs somehow.

Theoretically, it should be possible to make a certificate that does both code signing and SSL, but I'm not sure you want that.  If something should happen, it would be nice to be able to isolate the two functions.  Also, I'm pretty sure you'd have to call the certificate vendors and ask if they did this, and if they don't, having them do it will likely jack up the price quite high.

As far as vendor, things to consider:

- The technology is pretty much all the same.  These days, aim for a minimum of 128 bit keys, I'd probably bump it up to 256, but I'm paranoid.
- Beyond browser acceptabiliy, the only reason to pay more would be name recognition.  Among the paranoid security wonks, I'd expect RSA, Thawte, Verisign and GeoTrust to have very good reputations.  Probably EnTrust, too.  This probably only matters if you are dealing with a security focused product.  I think your average user will not be so aware.
- From a security geek perspective - you're only as safe as the security of your Root CA (Certificate Authority).  For the truly paranoid, the thing to do would be to dig into the background material of how the company hosts its root and issuing CAs, how are they physically securited?  network security?  personnel access control?  Also - do they have public CRLs (Certificate Revocation Lists), how do you get a cert revoked?  Do they offer OCSP (Online Certificate Status Protocol)?  How do they check out certificate requestors to be sure they are giving the right cert to the right person?  ... All this stuff really matters if you are offering something that must be highly secure.  Things like medical records, financial managment applications, tax information, etc should be highly protected.  Most web apps aren't so high risk and probably don't require this degree of scrutiny.

On that last bullet - if you dig into the Verisigns of the world - the very expensive certs - you're likely to see the value.  They have a massive infrastructure and take the security of their CAs very seriously.  I'm not so sure about the super-cheap hosting services.  That said, if your risk is low, US$300 for an SSL Cert doesn't make much sense compared to US$12.99!!

Comment: The "green bar" is what really matters. Do those cheap offers give a green bar?

Comment: The green bar is not a 1:1 relationship with the service provider.  It can be dependent on browser configuration, network configuration, the accuracy of your certificate application paperwork, and the diligence with which you manage your PKI.

Comment: Browsers display the 'Green Bar' when they detect that a site is using an Extended Validation SSL cert - list of browsers with screenshots of how they show Standard vs Extended validation here: https://www.expeditedssl.com/pages/visual-security-browser-ssl-icons-and-design.html

Answer (score 9):

So for web site / application servers you need an SSL certificate. You do *not* need an EV certificate. I've used ones from QuickSSL for this, as unlike some of the other cheap certificate providers they don't require the installation of an intermediate certificate on the server - that's a no-one for me.

For signing applications that's a different type of certificate altogether (kind of, it's still an X509 certificate, but the one you use for your web site is not one you can use to sign an application). You need an authenticode signing certificate from the likes of [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/products-services/security-services/code-signing/digital-ids-code-signing/) or [Globalsign](http://www.globalsign.com/developer/code-signing-certificate/index.htm). These are a magnitude more expensive than a plain old SSL certificate and require you to be an incorporated company and produce those documents.

Comment: the code will be downloaded (at least the first time) using a browser, so I need the EV so that the user knows he's really downloading a file from a trusted website, don't I?

Comment: No you don't. If all you want is for the installer to show who it's from and that it hasn't been tampered with then you need a code signing certificate. You don't even need a certificate on foo.com for that - the code signing will show your company details.