# Certificate type used for SAML Signature

Tags: ssl, certificate, saml, signing, ca

We have to send a SAML Response XML converted into a Base64 String to a vendor using a self-posting form.

I have setup the SAML and I have signed it with a certificate, but the certificate I used was the wrong one. The vendor asked for a certificate acquired from a CA (Certification Authority).

The problem is I do not know which certificate to choose from at the CA. I'm looking at the type of certificates I can buy from verisign. The two options is a SSL certificate or a Code Signing certificate.

Any thoughts on what certificate I need? And an explanation would be welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

For your use, you want the SSL certificate.

There's a great explanation for the differences between the types in [this other SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502822/what-ssl-certificate-do-i-need).