# Publisher : Unkonwn + code signing certificate in Visual studio project in Setup.exe and vsto file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, outlook, certificate

I have create Outlook add-in for the client. I have created the setup project for that. When I run my setup file it prompts for the trust and show `Publisher : Unknown`. And after installation when I open Outlook it again prompts for `VSTO` trust and again shows `Publisher: Unknown`.

My questions are:

1. My client has SSL certificate from GoDaddy. Can I use this certificate to sign my code?
2. If I sign my code using the SSL Certificate, Will both the publisher became known?
3. I have found something to add certificate in project using project property > Signing > Add Certificate from file. Will this help me to sign my setup file and my VSTO file?

I have searched on google for this but it confused me more.
Can anyone help me to solve this?
Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an SSL certificate for code signing. Check this SO question for details: [What SSL certificate do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502822/what-ssl-certificate-do-i-need)

In regard to 3), you are probably refering to [giving an assembly a strong name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [This is  different from code signing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/03/what-s-the-difference-part-five-certificate-signing-vs-strong-naming.aspx) and serves a different purpose.